Clarify the exceptions to shareholder approval for a merger in a corporation
According to the book "Essay Exam Writing for the California Bar Exam" by Mary Basick and Tina Schindler, 2nd edition, page 38,

Merger occurs when one corporation acquires another corporation. Typically requires shareholder approval.

Exception for shareholder approval: Shareholder approval of the surviving corporation is not needed where the change is not significant (this occurs when the articles will remain the same, shareholders hold the same number of shares, and the voting power of the shares issued will not be more than 20%).

Short-form merger allowed where a 90%-owned subsidiary is merged into the corporate owner (no approval needed by subsidiary).



My problem is the bolded part of the quote.
What is it referring to by "the voting power of the shares issued"? What shares are being issued here? The shareholders from the surviving corporation still hold the same number of shares. So what is it talking about?


What is it referring to by "the voting power of the shares issued"?
What shares are being issued here? The shareholders from the surviving
corporation still hold the same number of shares. So what is it
talking about?

The example assumes that Big Corp. acquires Small Corp. in exchange for Small Corp. shareholders other than Big Corp. receiving Big Corp. shares.
If less than 20% of the voting shares of Big Corp. post-merger are Big Corp. voting shares issued to Small Corp. shareholders other than Big Corp., then shareholder approval is not required from Big Corp. shareholders under the default rules of California corporate law.
So, suppose that there are 8,500 voting shares of Big Corp. before the merger, and Big Corp. acquires Small Corp. which was 50% owned by Big Corp. and 50% owned by other shareholders. Then Big Corp. issues 1,500 equal voting shares of Big Corp. to the shareholders of Small Corp. that owned 50% of Small Corp. prior to the merger.
After the merger, the pre-merger shareholders of Big Corp. own 8,500 voting shares of Big Corp. and the pre-merger shareholders of Small Corp. own 1,500 voting shares of Big Corp. Post-merger, there are 10,000 equal voting shares of Big Corp. outstanding, of which 15% of them are owned by former shareholders of Small Corp.
So, the approval of Big Corp.'s shareholders is not required, only the approval of Small Corp.'s shareholders is required.

This is a super good answer. I want to make sure I understand it though. In your hypo, I assume that all the shareholders have voting power. So the shareholders of small corp now have 15% voting power in Big corp. None of the big corp shareholders had their number of shares changed. And yet they have suffered a 15% decrease in voting power. And that is ok because it is below 20% voting power. Thus, no need to get consent from big corp shareholders. Is that right?

@SJ Yes. That is correct.

@SJ The basic idea is that approval is required if the merger will dilute the value of the original shareholders' shares too much. "too much" is defined as >20%.
